# Reinitilize Variable Inside a loop. Help me understand its impact in the code below

Tags: javascript, loops

```js
function zeroArray(m, n) {
  // Creates a 2-D array with m rows and n columns of zeroes

  let newArray = [];
  let row = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    // Adds the m-th row into newArray

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // Pushes n zeroes into the current row to create the columns
      row.push(0);
      console.log(row);
    }
    // Pushes the current row, which now has n zeroes in it, to the array
    
    newArray.push(row);

  }
  return newArray;
}

let matrix = zeroArray(3, 2);
console.log(matrix);
```

In this code I'm to reinitialize the row variable in the outer loop to an empty array inorder to create a 2D array with rows and columns that look like this: [[0,0], [0,0], [0,0]].
Without reinitializing the variable I get a completely different outcome.
I understand how the code works but I dont understand the full impact of the reinitializing. Why would setting the row variable back to an empty array create a different ouptut?

Comment: If you keep adding to *one single* array, then you just keep growing that *one single array*. And just add the one single array in multiple places in `newArray` but that is just the same reference repeated over and over.

Comment: You need to create a new array on every iteration, else... you're pushing (and mutating) the same array

Comment: Thanks I get it now, I would just be growing the row array if I don't reinitialize but I need to set it back empty so I could push a _new_ row array to the newArray.